# Change artifact version name on artifactory rest api/build/promotion

Tags: curl, jenkins, gradle, artifactory, promotions

I am using Gradle to build my application and artifactory to store/resolve binaries and Jenkins-CI to automate builds.

So far I am using single-project structure in Gradle to build.

For each build I am overwriting existing jars in artifactory under snapshot libs and also I am using release libs to store production builds.

When I am trying to promote artifacts from snapshot to release using the below curl rest api, I am able to promote, but I'm not able to change/override the version name on the release artifact.

REST API to promote:

```
curl -X POST -u admin:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "status": "Go Green",
  "ciUser": "jenkinsAdmin",
  "sourceRepo" : "libs-snapshot-local",
  "targetRepo":"libs-release-local",
  "copy": true
}' "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/build/promote/buildName/buildNumber"
```

Output from the above API call:

```
../dev/abc-dev.jar[promotion happens from snapshot to release libs]../dev/abc-dev.jar
```

## Trying For

1. whether it possible override version name on api/build/promotion..

   ../dev/abc-dev.jar --> ../release/abc-release.jar
2. For roll-back scenario how we can achieve here..

Please Provide your inputs & suggestion.

Thanks.